# NDC and webflux

Tags: spring, project-reactor, spring-webflux

I want to enable NDC in my Spring webflux application. Upon a HTTP request arrival i wanna enrich all my logging statements for the sake of that particular request with some request specific context information like requestId/clientId and so on. 
I do **not** need to propagate this request specific context information to any downstream calls or whatever - i simply look for a solution for a single, in-process NDC logging...

In a regular MVC application one would use NDC for that but as we are not in thread-per-request world things got hairy

I looked into https://jira.spring.io/si/jira.issueviews:issue-html/SPR-15680/SPR-15680.html
or https://github.com/rstoyanchev/context-holder 
but using

```
Mono.currentContext().flatMap
```

just for the sake of logging seems like overkill and inconvenience...
Any ideas/examples how it can be nicely in spring webflux ?

Comment: It is not single and not in process it is multi threaded and hence you loose it. You will need to propagate the context to each call.

Comment: @Martin I mean "single and in-process" by having a single application, NO JVM-to-JVM or host-to-host communication. I am fully aware there are threads - equal to number of cores but it is still single application not "microservice thing". Seems like spring sleuth is claiming to have NDC solved for webflux but i am wondering if there is no easier approach ...

Comment: Then take a look at the code spring sleuth. As stated it is multi threaded, as the NDC/MDC is based on `ThreadLocal` storage you need a way to pass around that data between threads. You would also need to find a way to cleanup after yourself when processing finished (else you are leaking data into other threads and you don't want that).

Comment: I have come up with a simple-ish solution around `doOnEach` (which lets' you access the `Context`), have a look at the blog post I linked in the comments of this SPR issue.

Comment: @Simon Thx a lot. The only inconvenience is that all logging needs to be performed from doOn* methods (as context is passed within signal). Looks like one can only easily log reactive events and NDC for logging within operator methods is not doable.
For my own curiosity: I noticed that if I set NDC explicitly in a controller method then calling LOG directly(within body of operator method like map, thenMany) is with NDC being set. As soon as I use flatMap - seems like inner publishers are run on different thread, no NDC is active and one would need to use doOn* methods to read reactor context